# Calculate time needed to brute force a password

Tags: connections

> When the maximum time required to find an 8-character password
>   consisting of only 26 lowercase alphabetic characters in a brute force
>   fashion is 1, the maximum required time is
>   **?**  if the length of the password is extended to 10 characters. Also, even when the length of the password remains 8 characters, the
>   maximum required time is **?**  if uppercase alphabetic characters
>   are used as well.

I would love to know the method to solve this kind of question. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: with 8 characters password, 26 lowercase, you have 26 choices for each character, i.e. $26^8$ combinations (so you have the "speed"). With 10 characters, 26 choices per character, you have $26^{10}$ combinations; with also upper cases, you have 52 choices per character...

Comment: Great! So the result is 676 and 256 respectively! Thanks alot!